# How to configure axis using characters and draw graphs? (tikzpicture)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, characters, axis

I am new to LateX and want to draw a graph with letters on my Y-axis and values on my X-axis.Unfortunately it is not working as expected. I would like to have all values (A to Z) on my Y-axis and the values [0,100] on my X-axis.

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
                    ytick=data,
                    yticklabels={,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,
                    U,V,W,X,Y,Z},
                    height=16cm,
                    xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,80,80,90,100},
                    width =12cm
                    ]

      %Graph: y=B
      %\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (B); not working
      %Graph: x=40
      %Draw Value (50,C)
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

results in the following output:

[image]

How do I draw values like (50,C) and functions like y=B in my graph?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Comment: thanks for the info! I completed the fragment to a runnable code. :-)

Comment: `{A,...,Z}` is supported

Comment: Where do I find documentation on this? @percusse

Comment: The `...` syntax is documented in chapter 83 *Repeating things: the foreach statement* of the manual for `pgf`/TikZ. It does not work in `symbolic y coords` (cf. my answer) though, there you must specify the coordinates explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are not entirely clear to me, but it sounds like you might want to have a look at `symbolic y coords`:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic y coords={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,
                    U,V,W,X,Y,Z},
    % symbolic coords have a numeric distance of 1
    ytick distance=1,
    xtick={0,10,...,100},
    height=16cm,
    width =12cm,
    xmin=0,xmax=100,
    % in order to set limits for a symbolic axis, we need [normalized]
    ymin={[normalized] 0},
    ymax={[normalized] 25}
    ]

      %Graph: y=B
      \addplot[blue, ultra thick] coordinates {(0,B)(100,B)};
      %Graph: x=40
      \addplot [red,ultra thick] coordinates {(40,A)(40,Z)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is some sort of fun question, here comes a fun answer. You may use the `\InvAlph` function which, as indicated by its name, is the inverse of `\Alph`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\numA{1}
\def\numB{2}
\def\numC{3}
\def\numD{4}
\def\numE{5}
\def\numF{6}
\def\numG{7}
\def\numH{8}
\def\numI{9}
\def\numJ{10}
\def\numK{11}
\def\numL{12}
\def\numM{13}
\def\numN{14}
\def\numO{15}
\def\numP{16}
\def\numQ{17}
\def\numR{18}
\def\numS{19}
\def\numT{20}
\def\numU{21}
\def\numV{22}
\def\numW{23}
\def\numX{24}
\def\numY{25}
\def\numZ{26}
\newcommand{\InvAlph}[1]{\csname num#1\endcsname}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
                ytick={0,1,..., 26},
                yticklabels={,A,...,Z},
                height=16cm,
                xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,80,80,90,100},
                width =12cm
                ]
 \addplot[blue, domain = 0:10]{\InvAlph{B}};
 \addplot[blue, domain = 0:10]{\InvAlph{C}+\InvAlph{D}};
 \addplot[blue, domain = 0:10]{\InvAlph{Z}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice that this is a fun answer. The definition of `\InvAlph` is clumsy and, more importantly, fragile, i.e. it returns an error if you feed it with something different from `A`,... `Z`.

Comment: Well, besides the fact you did not respect my concern. The x-axis is still not giving 10,20,...,100 but 0, 0.2, 0.4,...1 - bad answer

Comment: @BPdone It is. Don't make false accusations. In this fun answer, I just pot short stretches such that this is not seen.